# Group data from two tables, multiple columns and rows, into one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to group key = value pairs that are each on its row, into one row groupped by ID.

table 1. wp_posts
keys: ID - post_title

table 2. wp_postmeta
keys: post_id, wpcf-owner, wpcf- tel, wpcf-mob, wpcf-email...

Using this query, I'm getting all info, but for each key I get separate row. What I need is an array where all is in one row groupped by wp_posts.ID

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'accommodation' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'wpcf%'
ORDER BY hic13_posts.post_title
```

Result is:

```
ID | post_title | key value  
------------------------------  
1  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-owner  
1  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-tel  
1  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-mob  
1  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-email  
2  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-owner  
2  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-tel  
2  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-mob  
2  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-email  
...
```

What I need is:

```
ID | post_title | key value  | key value | key value | key value  
-----------------------------------------------------------------  
1  |  TITLE     | wpcf-owner | wpcf-tel  | wpcf-mob  | wpcf-email  
2  |  TITLE     | wpcf-owner | wpcf-tel  | wpcf-mob  | wpcf-email
```

If I add command to group by ID, then I get only one key from second table...

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'accommodation' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'wpcf%'    
GROUP BY hic13_posts.ID
ORDER BY hic13_posts.post_title
```

I get only this

```
ID | post_title | key value  
------------------------------  
1  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-owner  
2  |  TITLE     |  wpcf-tel
```

Hope all this makes sense :-)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of transformation is a *pivot* but MySQL does not have a pivot function so you will need to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.:

```
SELECT p.ID, 
  p.post_title, 
  m.post_id, 
  max(case when m.meta_key = 'wpcf-owner' then m.meta_value end) as owner,
  max(case when m.meta_key = 'wpcf-tel' then m.meta_value end) as tel,
  max(case when m.meta_key = 'wpcf-mob' then m.meta_value end) as mob,
  max(case when m.meta_key = 'wpcf-email' then m.meta_value end) as email
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_postmeta m
  ON p.ID = m.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'accommodation' AND m.meta_key LIKE 'wpcf%'    
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title, m.post_id
ORDER BY p.post_title
```

Edit, if you have an unknown number of `meta_key` items to transform, then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic sql:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = ''',
      meta_key,
      ''' THEN m.meta_value else null END) AS `',
      meta_key, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM wp_postmeta;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT p.ID, 
              p.post_title, 
              m.post_id, ', @sql, ' 
            FROM wp_posts p
            JOIN wp_postmeta m
              ON p.ID = m.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type = ''accommodation'' 
               AND m.meta_key LIKE ''wpcf%''   
            GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title, m.post_id
            ORDER BY p.post_title');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Code generates error, but removing part 'AND p.meta_key LIKE 'wpcf%'' fixes it... one more thing, is there a way not to make a case for each and every meta_key since there are quite a few, and to make it future proof. All the keys start with 'wpcf-', hence I had this part'AND p.meta_key LIKE 'wpcf%''

Comment: @ronimarin The error was because I placed the wrong table alias on the `meta_key` in the where clause.  I also edited my answer to include a solution to generate dynamic sql for an unknown number of columns.

Comment: Thank you so much, been learning SQL for couple of hours to make this happen ;-) You definitely saved me quite a few hours!

Comment: First solution works like a charm :-) Second solution is unfortunately not working for me... ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = ', ' at line 1

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I do not understand this much SQL, edit gives different error, I tried to play with it a bit, but no luck... Your edited code gives: 
`failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '''' at line 1`

Comment: @ronimarin What version of MySQL are you using?  Where are you using the code? Here is a demo of a working version -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7326/3

Comment: MySQL 5.0.95, on CentOS 5.9, Apache 2.2.3, php 5.2.10... Testing directly on SQL server through Webmin interface...

Comment: @ronimarin If you are running this code in SQL Server it will not work.

Comment: Why? :confused: Where then? With php?

Comment: @ronimarin This code is MySQL specific you have to run it in a mysql stored proc or some sort of interface for MySQL.

Comment: Ok! I lost you now completely :-) Going to bed since it is 1am over here ;-) Thanks for helping out and good night for now.